# iptables - drops all connections despite previous rules

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

I am trying to allow ssh connections from the local network and drop all other connection attempts on the same port (22), here are my current rules in iptables:

```
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

All of the articles I have read elsewhere seem to say that adding these rules will allow local ssh access and drop all other connection attempts on port 22, however the last rule will always result in a dropped connection even from my local network.

If I only have the first two rules included in my configuration, I can SSH to the host without an issue, it is just when I add the final rule that the connection stops working from the local network and anywhere else

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

It seems as if the iptables rules are supposed to be read in a top down order so that if the connection does not satisfy any of the above rules it will eventually be dropped in the last rule, but this does not seem to be the case with these rules. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

iptables output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 852537 packets, 927902121 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       127.0.0.0/8          0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
       0        0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
     104     6384 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
     856    68020 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 29118 packets, 22261801 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
     856    68020 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Show us the actual rule set along with the packets counters. Do `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` and edit your question adding the output.

Comment: I missed your edit, but can not see what is wrong. The packet counters are also all 0 for the paths we want to look at. Are there any `nat` rules?